# In C++ Builder, how to execute a function inside a `TThread`?

Tags: multithreading, c++builder, vcl

I created a `TThread` using the `File > New > Other > Thread Object` menu.  It gave me some boilerplate code, like this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <System.hpp>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit2.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

//   Important: Methods and properties of objects in VCL can only be
//   used in a method called using Synchronize, for example:
//
//      Synchronize(&UpdateCaption);
//
//   where UpdateCaption could look like:
//
//      void __fastcall MyThreadClass::UpdateCaption()
//      {
//        Form1->Caption = "Updated in a thread";
//      }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__fastcall MyThreadClass::MyThreadClass(bool CreateSuspended)
    : TThread(CreateSuspended)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall MyThreadClass::Execute()
{
    NameThreadForDebugging(System::String(L"MyThread"));
    //---- Place thread code here ----
    ShowMessage("Hello World!");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**header**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef Unit2H
#define Unit2H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MyThreadClass : public TThread
{
protected:
    void __fastcall Execute();
public:
    __fastcall MyThreadClass(bool CreateSuspended);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

I added the line you can see, `ShowMessage("Hello World!")`, and ran the program, but nothing happens besides my form being displayed.

How do I execute the code inside my thread function?

Comment: You can't `ShowMessage()` from a thread. Graphic controls (FMX or VCL) are not thread safe. All use of visual controls must be done by the main thread itself. This is documented in the generated source you've provided, in the large comment block at the top. Did you read the comment and code sample that's in it?

Comment: You need to create an instance of your class to actually create a thread and run the code. `someVar = new MyThreadClass(false);` But as Ken said calling ShowMessage is not safe.

Comment: @KenWhite I understand that I will have to use `Synchronize` at some point but I believe I should just learn how to get a `TThread` running first.  I think `ShowMessage()` should work even if it afterwards freezes my program (based on my previous experience with doing VCL stuff from a separate non-TThread thread).

Comment: @GirkovArpa: You cannot use `ShowMessage()` from a thread, as I mentioned before. It's a GUI call, and you cannot use the VCL without `Synchronize` (or `Queue` in more recent versions). There are NO exceptions. It simply will not work. I point you to my previous comment again.

Comment: From the code comment at the top of the generated unit (**emphasis mine**): *Important: **Methods and properties of objects in VCL can only be
//   used in a method called using Synchronize,*** Note the word ONLY in that sentence. *Only* is not ambiguous.

Comment: I will try without `ShowMessage()` but the thing is, I've already successfully used `ShowMessage()` from a separate `std::thread` without problems.  It's only when I try to add controls that I run into bugs like the window not repainting itself, or only part of itself.

Comment: @KenWhite I finally got it to do what I wanted:  My DLL created with C++ Builder adds controls to my form when told to by the host EXE.  But it uses a TThread that polls a variable for instructions, so the EXE has to execute a pointer to a DLL function to set the variable, then when the TThread sees the variable contains instructions it executes them.  This is convoluted and you seem very knowledgeable about this so do you have any suggestion for a better way to do this?  In particular `Synchronize` doesn't allow parameters so how can I get around that?  Should I post a new question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to replace the `ShowMessage("Hello World!")` line with this:

```cpp
Synchronize([](){ ShowMessage("Hello World!"); });
```

And create the thread with this:

```cpp
MyThreadClass* myThread = new MyThreadClass(false); // false == don't create suspended
```

Comment: Your lambda should use `[]` instead of `[&]` since it is not actually capturing anything. Also, the RTL has [`TThread::CreateAnonymousThread()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread) to run a lambda in a thread.  Also, the Win32 API `MessageBox()` is thread-safe, so you could use that instead of `ShowMessage()` and then you wouldn't need `Synchronize()` anymore to show a popup message.